# Popup in page with custom css without overriding page's css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've a problem that I'm not really sure if can be solved: 
I want to have a modal that pops up in sites of my clients. If a user goes to a client page, after some second, my pop up will appear.

I have built my modal pop up using bootstrap, jquery and some other javascript.

The problem is: there is a way to avoid the inclusion of my css in my clients' pages? This is because, maybe, one of them does not use bootstrap and using it will change the presentation of his page.

So, there is a way to include only a javascript that calls my server to get the information it needs (css etc...)?

I thought that I could include my code in an Iframe, but there is a way to have the pop up display in the parent window?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Think about this one....would you want anyone to pop up windows for visiting your site? Probably not....so it's very much by design. You could do the iframe, but there's ways to disable people using their sites through iframe also for the very reason mentioned above. If this was easily done, the entire internet would be filled with garbage advertisements etc everywhere you browsed.

Comment: Can't you place your modal in another file that doesnt contain the css reference?

Comment: You are right. But my clients do want this kind of thing. The pop up shows information that it's taken from my personal server

Comment: Well, you can just insert your modal inside an iframe. js, css and html will be encapsulated inside a new window so there will be no effect on parent window (the customer site). You can deploy it by creating a simple js script that will be included on client website. Otherwise, you will have to inline all styles or make the modal match what is on the clients websites.

Comment: @pawel-kuznik but I think that the modal will remain inside the iframe with this method, am I wrong?

Comment: no. The idea is to create a modal (a most simple div with inlined styles) that will hold iframe with your blackboxes styles, structure and code. This way you can distribute the modal without affecting parent page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have solved the problem with a workaround. I use a pop up that takes data from an iframe. My clients need only to include the javascript code for the pop up and nothing more; everything else will stay on my server and will be retrived once the pop up "makes" the call.